# BigQuery unnest percentile struct to a table with columns

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

I have a table which looks like below

| id | city | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bacelona | 300 |
| 2 | Barcelona | 200 |
| 3 | London | 1000 |
| 4 | London | 2000 |

I want to create a table with percentiles per city
I am creating a struct with the below query

```
SELECT AS STRUCT City, APPROX_QUANTILES(CAST(Price as INTEGER), 100) AS quants
  FROM T
  where Price > 0
  group by City
```

How can I flatten (unnest) the struct into a table with the below columns
City, Offset, Qant

which includes all percentiles for all available cities in the source table T?

I will appreciate your help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At first I generate your table `with T as ()`

Then using your query to obtain QUANTILES (only 10 here to make the example more readable). Then is data is `unnest` and with the `row_number` each line gets an index value. Pivot puts each number in a column. The numbers from 1 to 100 have to be written by hand.

```
With T as (
Select 1 id,    "Bacelona" city,    300  price UNION ALL 
select 2,"Barcelona",   200 UNION ALL 
select 3,"London",  1000 UNION ALL 
select 4,"London",  2000 
)

SELECT *
from(
SELECT city,quant,row_number() over (partition by city) as r
from (
SELECT AS STRUCT City, APPROX_QUANTILES(CAST(Price as INTEGER), 10) AS quants, row_number() over (partition by city) as r
  FROM T
  where Price > 0
  group by City
), unnest(quants) as quant
)
pivot( min(quant) for r in ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) )
```

If the column names should be named:

```
SELECT city,quant,concat("quant",cast(row_number() over (partition by city) as string)) as r
...
pivot( min(quant) for r in ( "quant1","quant2","quant3") )
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Samuel. This has been very helpful.

Could you please tell me how to use lag() function to show a result table as 

City, quant, pre-quant

but using the data per city (like partition by city but lag function takes order by). The problem is that the first pre-quant of the second city is filled with the last quant of the first city. How to make it null ?